# How to get the contacts list in a sony ericsson in J2Me

Tags: java-me, contacts, sony, pim

I'm building a phone application in j2me. In it, I need to get the contacts from the phonebook. There is an API for that and the line I tried to use was

```
contactList = (ContactList) PIM.getInstance().openPIMList(PIM.CONTACT_LIST, 
               PIM.READ_ONLY, name);
```

Apparently, it doesn't work in my phone (Sony Ericsson W705).
That's why I was wondering whether there is a different API that I can access the phonebook in J2Me. If there is such an option, how can I check whether the person running the application has a sony ericsson (or nokia, samsung..)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Sony-Ericsson W705 supports JSR-75 (file and PIM access API) - e.g. [look here](http://devices.getjar.com/device/Sony-Ericsson/W705)
2. There's no other API which supports PIM access
3. You can't check dynamically does particular phone supports given API or not? Common practice is to build several versions for different phones.